# Can I still enter any Schengen member state if I have been denied entry to another?

Tags: visas, schengen, trains, denial-of-entry

I was held at the Polish borders when I attempted to enter by train. They took my fingerprints and sent me back with a written document. I respected the decision and returned immediately.

The document is in Polish concerning the decision taken, and I don't understand it. I am from Cameroon. My limited understanding from what was explained in English at the time was that the asylum status I requested was denied me. I only realised later that I asked the wrong authorities (border guards instead of immigration officers).

This was exactly one year and three months ago now. Do I still have access to any Schengen country?

Comment: What did the document say? Also what is your nationality?

Comment: THE document is in Polish concerning the decision taken,, and I don't understand it, I am Cameroon.. all what I understood as was explained in English was the asylum status I requested which was denied me. it is later I realise that I asked from the wrong authorities (border guards) instead of immigration officers

Comment: Are you seeking to go to a Schengen country as a refugee? If so that's a whole different matter, and not really suitable for this site, which is about tourism-type travel. You might try the 'Expatriates' site at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: now I want to apply for a student Visa...

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile to get a translation of that document. If you can retype it accurately, then [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) might be enough. Then you'll know generally what it says.

Comment: @Adada You most definitely cannot apply for a student visa at the border so the question about “entering” a Schengen country is moot. Each Schengen country can still decide to grant you a visa or not but based on the few details you gave us, it seems quite likely such visa would be refused. You need to apply for it in advance in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If you received a ban, it's a ban from the whole Schengen area. If you haven't received a ban, formally you can still (try to) enter any Schengen country, including Poland but the reasons that led to being denied entry in the first place might still hold and the denial itself will weight against you.

If they notice the cancelled entry stamp (that should be) in your passport, border guards in other Schengen countries are likely to evaluate your situation more carefully than usual. But they are still allowed to let you enter, if they think it's appropriate. Either way, it's difficult to know for sure in advance.

Furthermore, if you need a visa (that would depend on your nationality), you need to apply for it in advance.